# Not calling base class constructor from derived class

Tags: c++, class, derived-class

Say I have a base class:

```
class baseClass  
{  
  public:  
baseClass() { };

};
```

And a derived class:

```
class derClass : public baseClass
    {  
      public:  
    derClass() { };

    };
```

When I create an instance of  `derClass` the constructor of `baseClass` is called. How can I prevent this?

Comment: You don't; that doesn't make sense. Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: @GMan I have a base class where the data is prepared with a header in the constructor. The derived class doesn't need a header prepared, but it's calling the base class constructor which is preparing a header and messes some things up.

Comment: You're missing the point of inheritance.  Inheritance forms an "an A is a B" relationship.  If a B does things that an A should not do, then an A is not a B.

Comment: Please read [this](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Ask about the *whole problem you're trying to solve*, not the step you think you need to take.

Comment: change the base class, not the derived class.

Answer (score 21):

Make an additional empty constructor.

```
struct noprapere_tag {};

class baseClass  
{  
public:  
  baseClass() : x (5), y(6) { };

  baseClass(noprapere_tag()) { }; // nothing to do

protected:
  int x;
  int y;

};

class derClass : public baseClass
{  
public:  
    derClass() : baseClass (noprapere_tag) { };

};
```

Comment: >derClass() : baseClass (noprapere_tag) { };
In this line noprapere_tag is not an object, shouldnt you create an object?

Answer (score 9):

A base class instance is an integral part of any derived class instance. If you successfully construct a derived class instance you must - by definition - construct all base class and member objects otherwise the construction of the derived object would have failed. Constructing a base class instance involves calling one of its constructors.

This is fundamental to how inheritance works in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Sample working program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class A
{
    public:
    A()
    {
        cout<<"a\n";
    }
    A(int a)
    {}
};
class B:public A
{
    public:
    B() : A(10)
    {
        cout<<"b\n";
    }
   
};
int main()
{
    
    new A;
    cout<<"----------\n";
    new B;
    
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
a                                                                                                        
----------                                                                                               
b
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a protected (possibly empty) default constructor which would be used by the derived class:

```
class Base {
protected:
  Base() {}

public:
  int a;
  
  Base(int x) {a = 12;}
};

class Derived : Base {
public:
  Derived(int x) {a = 42;}
};
```

This will block any external code from using default `Base` constructor (and thus not initializing `a` properly). You just need to make sure you initialize all the `Base` fields in the `Derived` constructor as well.